# Getting undefined "results" when using .map()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, object, methods

I'm trying to access my Title value with `map` but I'm getting an error stating that "results" is undefined. Based on the JS object's structure, I'm not sure why the error's coming up. I can't tell which results it's referring to, but I believe it's the first one.

```
]).then(axios.spread((cat) => {
            _categories = cat.data.d.results;

// irrelevant code here

loadCategories(){

        let categs = _categories,

            trainingCrs = _categories.d.results.Courses.results.map(x => x.Title);

            console.log(trainingCrs);

}
```

#### JSON snippet:

```
 {
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "N/A",
          "type": "N/A"
        },
        "Courses": {
          "results": [
            {
              "__metadata": {
                "id": "N/A",
                "type": "N/A"
              },
              "Title": "Capuchin Monkey"
            },
            {
              "__metadata": {
                "id": "N/A",
                "type": "N/A"
              },
              "Title": "Capybara"
            },
```

Comment: You cannot use  `map` on JSON, but suspect you are not really talking about JSON, but a JavaScript object. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: First, please check with `console.log(typeof jsonOBJ);`, and if printed 'string', then `jsonOBJ = JSON.parseString(jsonOBJ)`

Comment: Also, what is the result of `console.log(_categories.d.results.Courses.results);` ?

Comment: It should be `_categories.d.results[0].Courses.results`, because the both `results` are arrays. The `[0]` selects the first element, but maybe you need a `map` (or `flatMap`) there too.